# How to get a certain values out of a .dat file trough the parameter?

Tags: linux, bash

So, I have a .dat file that contains the ID of a person, name, surname, place where he/she lives...
example:

> 0 Alex Brooks Conway 312 Scotland

I need to make a flag -search which will take extra parameters -name -surname and will print (echo) out only the people who match the conditions.

So for example:
`-search -name "Alex" -surname "Brooks"`
 and it will print out everyone that matches these flags.

I'm kinda lost since I could do it with awk or grep but I'm not sure which is better and how exactly to do it

Comment: In awk, you can access fields using `$1` , `$2` ... and pass variable using `-v`

Comment: You mean you want a script that can parse option/flag? Please update your question and clarify what do you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bash script that might do what you wanted. In this example the name of the is `myscript`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Initialize the variables
name=
file=
surname=

##: If there are no options/arguments given
[[ $1 ]] || { echo "Give me something!" >&2
  printf '%s\n' "Usage: -s|--surname -n|--name -f|--file" >&2
  exit 1
}

##: loop through the options/arguments

while (($#)); do
  case $1 in
    -n|--name)
      shift
      name=$1
      ;;
    -s|--surname)
      shift
      surname=$1
      ;;
    -f|--file)
      shift
      file=$1;;
    *)
      printf 'Illegal option! %s\n' "$1"  >&2
      printf '%s\n' "Usage: -s|--surname -n|--name -f|--file" >&2
      exit 1;;
  esac
  shift
done

##: If no file what given
if [[ -z $file  ]]; then
  echo "No file given!" >&2
  exit 1
fi

##: Loop through the file line-by-line and check for a match
##: You should be using awk here but I'll leave that to the awk masters :-)

while read -ra line; do
  if [[ ${line[@]} == *" $name $surname "* ]]; then
    if [[ $name == ${line[1]} && $surname == ${line[2]} ]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "${line[*]}"
      exit 0
    fi
  else
     printf '%s %s was not found!\n' >&2 "$name" "$surname"
     exit 1
  fi
done < "$file"
```

Howto use

```
./myscript -n Alex -s Brooks -f file.dat
```

Or using the long options

```
./myscript --name Alex --surname Brooks --file file.dat
```

- Need more testing and error checking, like for example that if the file given was not really a file but a directory and so on.